# Share of treated firms in a neighbourhood over time in Stata

Tags: loops, sum, share, stata

I want to create a new variable indicating the share of treated firms for each state and year separately, that is Treated firms/Total number of firms in the state for each year. Thus, I need to sum up all unique ID for each year and state and repeat the same procedure only for treated firms. Treatment is time-varying which means that firms receive treatment in different years.

Would be grateful for suggestions on the implementation in Stata.
[image]

Comment: This was a comment on your previous question, which still applies. Please include a data example directly in your question, not indirectly as an image. See the tag wiki for more detail: stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want appears just to be a mean

```
 egen wanted = mean(treated), by(state  year)
```